# Sympy - Display Full Equation in Dense Matrix Form

Tags: python, matrix, sympy

I am attempting to use [Sympy](http://sympy.org/en/index.html?utm_source=%5Bdeliciuos%5D&utm_medium=twitter) to decompose estimation procedures within the IPython Notebook.  It would be very useful to be able to accompany data manipulations with the full linear equation display at each step.  To take a simple regression example, I have the following setup:

```
from sympy import *
from sympy.abc import epsilon

y=MatrixSymbol('y',5,1)
x=MatrixSymbol('x',5,2)
b=MatrixSymbol('b',2,1)
e=MatrixSymbol('epsilon',5,1)
```

I can print each of the components...

```
y.as_explicit()
```

[image]

```
(b*x).as_explicit()
```

[image]

```
e.as_explicit()
```

[image]

...but I have not been able to find, however, a method in Sympy that allows for the full equation to be displayed (the following was rendered with an [online latex editor](http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php)):

[image]

Basically any time I use an equals operator it is reasonably taken as assignment, and addition operators convert the **MatrixSymbol** into a **MatAdd** object, which does not support the `as_explict()` method. Any thoughts on this issue would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you make a typo? `b*x` is misaligned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you call the `MatAdd` constructor explicitly, it doesn't evaluate. To create an equality, use `Eq`.  It seems there is a rendering but with the plus sign in the Unicode pretty printing, which I opened https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/2747 for.

```
In [14]: Eq(y.as_explicit(), MatAdd((x*b).as_explicit(), (e).as_explicit()))
Out[14]:
⎡y₀₀⎤ = ⎡x₀₀⋅b₀₀ + x₀₁⋅b₁₀⎤ + ⎡ε₀₀⎤
⎢   ⎥   ⎢                 ⎥   ⎢   ⎥
⎢y₁₀⎥   ⎢x₁₀⋅b₀₀ + x₁₁⋅b₁₀⎥   ⎢ε₁₀⎥
⎢   ⎥   ⎢                 ⎥   ⎢   ⎥
⎢y₂₀⎥   ⎢x₂₀⋅b₀₀ + x₂₁⋅b₁₀⎥   ⎢ε₂₀⎥
⎢   ⎥   ⎢                 ⎥   ⎢   ⎥
⎢y₃₀⎥   ⎢x₃₀⋅b₀₀ + x₃₁⋅b₁₀⎥   ⎢ε₃₀⎥
⎢   ⎥   ⎢                 ⎥   ⎢   ⎥
⎣y₄₀⎦   ⎣x₄₀⋅b₀₀ + x₄₁⋅b₁₀⎦   ⎣ε₄₀⎦
```

It seems the LaTeX printing is correct, though:

```
In [16]: print(latex(Eq(y.as_explicit(), MatAdd((x*b).as_explicit(), (e).as_explicit()))))
\left[\begin{matrix}y_{0, 0}\\y_{1, 0}\\y_{2, 0}\\y_{3, 0}\\y_{4, 0}\end{matrix}\right] = \left[\begin{matrix}x_{0, 0} b_{0, 0} + x_{0, 1} b_{1, 0}\\x_{1, 0} b_{0, 0} + x_{1, 1} b_{1, 0}\\x_{2, 0} b_{0, 0} + x_{2, 1} b_{1, 0}\\x_{3, 0} b_{0, 0} + x_{3, 1} b_{1, 0}\\x_{4, 0} b_{0, 0} + x_{4, 1} b_{1, 0}\end{matrix}\right] + \left[\begin{matrix}\epsilon_{0, 0}\\\epsilon_{1, 0}\\\epsilon_{2, 0}\\\epsilon_{3, 0}\\\epsilon_{4, 0}\end{matrix}\right]
```

[image]

You can use `MatMul` if you don't want to evaluate the `x*b`:

```
In [18]: Eq(y.as_explicit(), MatAdd(MatMul(x.as_explicit(),b.as_explicit()), (e).as_explicit()))
Out[18]:
⎡y₀₀⎤ = ⎡x₀₀  x₀₁⎤⋅⎡b₀₀⎤ + ⎡ε₀₀⎤
⎢   ⎥   ⎢        ⎥ ⎢   ⎥   ⎢   ⎥
⎢y₁₀⎥   ⎢x₁₀  x₁₁⎥ ⎣b₁₀⎦   ⎢ε₁₀⎥
⎢   ⎥   ⎢        ⎥         ⎢   ⎥
⎢y₂₀⎥   ⎢x₂₀  x₂₁⎥         ⎢ε₂₀⎥
⎢   ⎥   ⎢        ⎥         ⎢   ⎥
⎢y₃₀⎥   ⎢x₃₀  x₃₁⎥         ⎢ε₃₀⎥
⎢   ⎥   ⎢        ⎥         ⎢   ⎥
⎣y₄₀⎦   ⎣x₄₀  x₄₁⎦         ⎣ε₄₀⎦

In [19]: print(latex(Eq(y.as_explicit(), MatAdd(MatMul(x.as_explicit(),b.as_explicit()), (e).as_explicit()))))
\left\[\begin{matrix}y_{0, 0}\\y_{1, 0}\\y_{2, 0}\\y_{3, 0}\\y_{4, 0}\end{matrix}\right\] = \left\[\begin{matrix}x_{0, 0} & x_{0, 1}\\x_{1, 0} & x_{1, 1}\\x_{2, 0} & x_{2, 1}\\x_{3, 0} & x_{3, 1}\\x_{4, 0} & x_{4, 1}\end{matrix}\right\] \left\[\begin{matrix}b_{0, 0}\\b_{1, 0}\end{matrix}\right\] + \left\[\begin{matrix}\epsilon_{0, 0}\\\epsilon_{1, 0}\\\epsilon_{2, 0}\\\epsilon_{3, 0}\\\epsilon_{4, 0}\end{matrix}\right\]
```

[image]

Comment: I did make a typo, but fortunately you were picking up what I was putting down anyway.  Much appreciated sir!